# java.lang.IllegalStateException ao declarar aspecto com Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, orientação-a-aspectos, aop

Estou tentando declarar o seguinte aspecto:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class UpperCaseAdvice {
     @Before("@target(annotations.Model)")
     public void toUpperCase(JoinPoint joinPoint){
          //faz alguma coisa
     }
}
```

Estou utilizando o spring-boot com tomcat embarcado. Ao tentar subir a aplicação, recebo a seguinte exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:245)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:212)
```

Aparentemente tentando criar o bean: `Error creating bean with name 'viewControllerHandlerMapping'`.

Se eu comento a anotação `@Before`, a aplicação sobe. Alguém ja enfrentou esse problema?

**Edit:** Debugando percebi que o problema está na criação do bean de configuração do Tiles. em Algum momento na criação do bean a classe ServletContextResource tenta montar uma url relativa ao caminho definido como local para as definições do tiles. No caso /tiles/tiles-config-global.xml .

Minha classe de configuração:

```
@Configuration
public class TilesConfigurations {

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver(){
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    resolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer(){
    TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
    configurer.setDefinitions("/tiles/tiles-config-global.xml");
    return configurer;
}
}
```

O que não entendo é o porque esse problema não acontece quando comento a anotação @Before

**Edit 2:** Full stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in class path resource [br/com/sigo/configurations/TilesConfigurations.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at    org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(  EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at br.com.sigo.BootApplication.main(BootApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResource(ApplicationContext.java:554) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResource(ApplicationContextFacade.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:153) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext.getResources(SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext.java:91) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.getSources(TilesConfigurer.java:306) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createLocaleDefinitionDao(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:182) ~[tiles-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:137) ~[tiles-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(TilesConfigurer.java:354) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:86) ~[tiles-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(TilesConfigurer.java:297) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:114) ~[tiles-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:64) ~[tiles-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(TilesConfigurer.java:271) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sigo</groupId>
<artifactId>sigo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <additionalProjectFacets>
                    <jst.web>3.1</jst.web>
                </additionalProjectFacets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Você pode dar mais detalhes do que o método `toUpperCase` faz? Se você deixar o método com a anotação `@Before`, mas deixar o conteúdo inteiro dele comentado com `/*` e `*/`, o que acontece?

Comment: @VictorStafusa a implementação do método está vazia. Eu não cheguei a implementar nada, pq a aplicação nem subia.

Comment: Tem o *stack trace* completo? Verificou se a versão da *servlet* API do projeto é a mesma provida pelo container? Se não, tente declarar a mesma versão que tem no container, mas como *provided* .

Comment: @BrunoCésar editei a minha pergunta adicionando a stack trace...lembrando que estou utilizando o spring boot para configuração do projeto. a servlet api que estou usando é a 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Roda o comando

```
 mvn dependency:tree
```

Provavelmente tem outra versão do servlet-api indo como dependencia.